# Unable to access svn repository through svn+ssh

Tags: svn

I have a bizzare problem on which I have spent a few hours to no avail. I have two SVN repositories on a server in the same directory. I am accessing them through svn+ssh in exactly the same manner but I am able to access one but not the other. Here are the details:

Repositories exist in /home/user1/repo1 and /home/user1/repo2.
I have set ssh so that authorized_keys file has an entry which looks something like this:

```
 command="svnserve -t --tunnel-user=user1 -r /home/user1/repo1",
  no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa ...
```

I have done that because the user has access to the server only for svn access to the repository and nothing else. 
Here is my problem. I can access /home/user1/repo1 through the following command:

```
svn co svn+ssh://user1@192.168.1.101/home/user1/repo1
```

But I cannot access

```
svn co svn+ssh://user1@192.168.1.101/home/user1/repo2
```

I can access repo2 using the file:/// Url locally on the server.

I can access repo2 remotely if I remove the "command=..." section from the autorized_key entry. That is, if I give unrestricted ssh access to the user. I tried that just to try and localize the problem.

I tried setting   SVN_SSH="ssh -v" to get verbose output.

The access failure occurs after this display:

```
debug1: Sending command: svnserve -t
```

The svnserve.conf files of both repositories are the same. I forgot how I had created the repository which does not give any problem. I created the new one which fails using *svnadmin create fullpath*  if that helps.

Comment: Your `command=` statement explicitly restricts the user to `repo1`, so I fail to understand your question.

Comment: @Richard Smith I am changing the command= statement. For some, I provide access to repo1 and some to repo2.  Problem found. It had to do with the -r option which provides the base to which the client-URL is appended.  I do not recollect how I had created repo1 some time back. The other one I created now. Both are in the same directories. I tried accessing repo2 as  _svn co svn+ssh://user1@192.168.1.101/repo2_ and it works. For repo1 I still need to provide the full URL though both are in the same directories! If you know why, please post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: **All** svn+ssh manuals clearly state for -r option: "<ReposRootPath> should be replaced with the **path to the directory containing your repositories.***"  You have one repo outside served tree, as Richard wrote to you

Comment: @LazyBadger  Both repositories are in the same folder. The same -r option is used and the same URL (of course with a different reponame) is used. Yet one works by specifying the full or absolute URL starting from root while the other works by specifying  the relative URL, relative to the -r path. Why?

Comment: Because (again!!!) `-r /home/user1/repo1`, while you have to have undestanding (after RTFM): for serving more than one repo by single svnserve you must to have root in the nearest common parent of repos (all repos served and accessible with relative-to-svnserve_root-path)

Comment: @Lazy Badger. Yes. I finally got it!